# Cypress freezing (Your tests are loading)

Tags: cypress

Cypress for me is often stuck in the "Your tests are loading" screen. I am really confused as to why it happens, and restarting Firefox/crome doesn't help either. It doesn't depend on any code, happens completely randomly and today my luck was down so I was looking more at that then at my code. any help is welcome, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Doing a force refresh once the test page opens up makes it work most times. But I am yet to figure out why it is happening.

Answer (score 7):

Late reply, but are you using webpack-preprocessor? I am and the same issue happened to me when I upgraded to Webpack 5 lately.
The solution was to downgrade to Webpack 4.

In this case it is a known issue, there is an open Pull Request on Cypress github that should hopefully fix it: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/15611

Answer (score 0):

If you're coding a project that's using another version and you install the project without using `nvm use` it will install the latest dependencies which may break the code that doesn't support the new dependencies version.
Check the original code Webpack version and be sure it is the same installed locally